# Drupal 6 programmatically adding \r\n showing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-nodes

I have a PHP script that adds story node to my drupal website:

```
function post_to_webpage($title, $body, $teaser, $promote) {
//set the working directory to your Drupal root
chdir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/webpage/');

//require the bootstrap include
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 
//(loads everything, but doesn't render anything)
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'story';
$node->title = $title;
$node->body = $body;
$node->teaser = $teaser;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->status = 1;
$node->promote = $promote;
$node->format = 2;
$node->sticky = 1;

node_save($node);

return $node->nid; }
```

however i frequently see r\n\ in the content of these nodes. What could cause this?

EDIT: Example output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vestibulum ultrices ultricies. Curabitur nibh risus, mattis rhoncus dignissim vel, laoreet sit amet neque. Praesent blandit arcu et nisl ornare semper. 
>  \r\n 
>   \r\n 
> Vestibulum eleifend malesuada odio, a aliquet mauris sagittis sed. Proin sit amet libero quis nibh malesuada mattis in sed urna. Nullam rutrum egestas interdum. Sed dui lorem, faucibus et sagittis in, volutpat at velit.

Comment: You're very vague, show an example of your output including the breaks in question.

Comment: You need to look into the [nl2br() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) either before you save the body of the node or before printing it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What would really be helpful is if you could post the text that you are submitting which results in the above output. However, based on what have said it sounds likely this problem is caused by an Input Format filter, or lack of a particular filter. A possible cause could be that the *Line break converter* filter is not enabled. To check your filters go to:

```
/admin/settings/filters/list
```

The default is *Filtered HTML*. Because you are adding the content programatically it is most likely that this is the filter being applied to your submission. Click on *configure* to the right of this entry. Scroll down the page looking for the filter called *"Line break converter"*. If this is not already enabled then click it on and *Save configuration*. Then try to create some new content in the same way.

You can find more information about the input filters at http://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/drupal-input-formats-and-filters.